# How to prevent background scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

On a click of a button, I have managed to fade the background but I also want the background to be unscrollable. I have also removed all the pointer events. Here is the class I add and remove on click of the button

```
.blur{
filter: blur(3px);
-webkit-filter: blur(3px);
-moz-filter: blur(3px);
-o-filter: blur(3px);
-ms-filter: blur(3px);
/* Anything blurred should be unclickable */
pointer-events: none;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I am still able to scroll. Any recommendations? :)

Have a nice day

Comment: The background of what exactly? The entire page, a div, etc?

Comment: Well the page, if any option in the menu is clicked, I want to background to freeze.Cause you can still scroll down. I want all the focus to the menu bar :)

Comment: Im making mainly for mobile using jquery mobile to avoid the user from going up or down and focus on the menu

Comment: @Indigo can you make fiddle

Comment: Hey! I made  js filddle and your code works perfectly. Im guessing something would be overlapping in my code! Thanks! :D http://jsfiddle.net/1j2zL3z7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
.blur{
position:fixed;
filter: blur(3px);
-webkit-filter: blur(3px);
-moz-filter: blur(3px);
-o-filter: blur(3px);
-ms-filter: blur(3px);
/* Anything blurred should be unclickable */
pointer-events: none;
overflow: hidden;
}
```